# quasiconvexity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $p>0$, $p\neq 1$. For $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n),x_i>0,\sum_ix_i=1$, $$f(x)=\sum_i (x_i/\|x\|_p)^{p-1}y_i,$$ where $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n),y_i>0,\sum_i y_i=1$ is fixed. Is $f$ quasiconvex? Plots ($n=2,3$) seem to suggest the claim to be true, but I couldn't prove. Any hints/suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Partial answer, edited after comment]. Not quasiconvex for $p>1$. Take $y=(1/n,\dots,1/n)$. For   $x=(1/n,\dots,1/n )$ we have $\|x\|_p = n^{1/p-1}$. Hence 
$$f(x) =    (n^{-1/p})^{p-1}   = n^{1/p -1 }$$
On the other hand, 
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} f(1-n\epsilon ,\epsilon,\dots,\epsilon) = 
f(1,0,\dots,0)   = n^{-1}$$
and the same for all other permutations of $1,0,\dots,0$.

Thus, for $\lambda\in (n^{-1},n^{1/p-1})$ the sublevel set $\{x:f(x)\le \lambda\}$   is not convex.

I do not know about $p<1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to stress that the function is not defined for all points in the positive orthant. I couldn't understand your statement "The function f is homogeneous of degree zero, so every sublevel set is a union of some half-lines beginning at the origin". If you can clarify this, it would be helpful...